# Javascript Async Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to call 3 functions in series however the last function also has a for loop in it I have the code below but when I run it I get the error for the `callback()` called after the `calanderItems.push()`:

```
if (called) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");


 async.series([

    function(callback){
        //some database query
                    callback();
    },
    function(callback){
                    //other database query
        callback();
    },
    function(callback){
        var google_calendar = new gcal.GoogleCalendar(req.user.accessToken);
        var calenderItems = [];
        google_calendar.calendarList.list(function(err, calendarList) {
            async.each(calendarList.items, function (item, callback){ 
                google_calendar.events.list(item.id, function(err, calenderItem) {
                    calenderItems.push(calenderItem);
                    callback();
                });
            },function(err){
                for (var element in prettyArray){
                    calenderitems.push(prettyArray[element])
                }
                console.log(calenderitems);
            });
        });
    }

]);
```

Comment: What is the error that you get ?  Callback was already called ?  Do you want the callback to be called only once in the third function or as many times as there are calendarItems ?

Comment: You never call the `callback` in the third function.  Is this intentional?  Normally, you'd do it in the final `async.each` function (after the loop over `prettyArray`, that is).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should change the code as follows:

```
if (called) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");


 async.series([

    function(callback){
        //some database query
                    callback();
    },
    function(callback){
                    //other database query
        callback();
    },
    function(callback){
        var google_calendar = new gcal.GoogleCalendar(req.user.accessToken);
        var calenderItems = [];
        google_calendar.calendarList.list(function(err, calendarList) {
            async.each(calendarList.items, function (item, callback){ 
                google_calendar.events.list(item.id, function(err, calenderItem) {
                    calenderItems.push(calenderItem);
                    callback();
                });
            },function(err){
                for (var element in prettyArray){
                    calenderItems.push(prettyArray[element]) // Be careful, you were using a variable that was not in the scope (calenderitems)
                }
                console.log(calenderItems);
                callback(); // This is necessary
            });
        });
    }

]);
```